# Custom v-repeat filter Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've quite new to Vue.js, only started experimenting with it two days ago - so apologies if this is a dumb question.

I have a list and I would like to set a limit on how many objects should be returned to the list. I created a custom filter:

```
Vue.filter('limit', function (value, number) {
    for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
        return value;
    }
});
```

And applied it:

```
<div class="project col-lg-4" v-repeat="projects | limit 3">
```

Yet nothing seems to change. I am aware that I could perform the limitation just using some extra js, but it would be nice to achieve this with a filter.
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a filter with `v-repeat`:

```
Vue.filter('limit', function (array, limit)
{
     return array.slice(0, limit);
});
```

and simply use it like so:

```
<li v-repeat="products | limit 3">
```